# Copy file from Azure Blob to ADLS File System using DataMovement Library

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to copy file from Azure Blob to Azure File System (Gen 2) using Data Movement Library but getting below error.

**C# Code**

```
var sourceUri = "https://[storage account name].blob.core.windows.net/container/sourcefolder/sourcefile.pdf"

     var sourceBlobFile = await CloudBlobContainer.ServiceClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(sourceUri);
    
    var destFileSystemFile = new CloudFile(destinationUri, CloudBlobContainer.ServiceClient.Credentials);
    
    TransferManager.CopyAsync(sourceBlobFile, destFileSystemFile , true);
```

**Error**

> Message: Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferException : The
> transfer failed.
>
> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException : An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.

**Error Stack Trace**

> at
> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferScheduler.ExecuteJobInternalAsync(TransferJob
> job, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
> C:\Local\Jenkins\jobs\DMLib_0.11.0\workspace\lib\TransferScheduler.cs:line
> 238    at
> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.SingleObjectTransfer.ExecuteAsync(TransferScheduler
> scheduler, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
> C:\Local\Jenkins\jobs\DMLib_0.11.0\workspace\lib\TransferJobs\SingleObjectTransfer.cs:line
> 198    at
> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferManager.DoTransfer(Transfer
> transfer, TransferContext transferContext, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) in
> C:\Local\Jenkins\jobs\DMLib_0.11.0\workspace\lib\TransferManager.cs:line
> 1322    at FileCopy.cs:line 39
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at FileCopyTests.cs:line 60
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> ----- Inner Stack Trace -----    at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsync[T](RESTCommand`1
> cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext,
> CancellationToken token)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferControllers.AsyncCopyController.StartCopyAsync()
> in
> C:\Local\Jenkins\jobs\DMLib_0.11.0\workspace\lib\TransferControllers\AsyncCopyControllers\AsyncCopyController.cs:line
> 473    at
> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferControllers.AsyncCopyController.DoWorkInternalAsync()
> in
> C:\Local\Jenkins\jobs\DMLib_0.11.0\workspace\lib\TransferControllers\AsyncCopyControllers\AsyncCopyController.cs:line
> 203    at
> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferControllers.TransferControllerBase.DoWorkAsync()
> in
> C:\Local\Jenkins\jobs\DMLib_0.11.0\workspace\lib\TransferControllers\TransferControllerBase.cs:line
> 175    at
> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferScheduler.ExecuteJobInternalAsync(TransferJob
> job, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
> C:\Local\Jenkins\jobs\DMLib_0.11.0\workspace\lib\TransferScheduler.cs:line
> 225 Result Message:
> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferException : The transfer
> failed.
> ---- Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException : An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.

Comment: Method [GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(String)](https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.getblobreferencefromserverasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlobContainer_GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync_System_String_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_AccessCondition_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_) ,the parameter String means=blobName.  What's your sourceUri?

Comment: Please change the souceUri to blobName, can try again.

Comment: Check your destination Uri and  have a look at https://blog.codingoutloud.com/2010/10/18/an-http-header-thats-mandatory-for-this-request-is-not-specified-one-cause-for-azure-error-message/

Comment: @LeonYue Updated the sample sourceuri

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT Some how for me its not showing into Fiddler

Answer (score 0):

I have find out that the current version of Data Movement Library doesn't support ADLS Gen 2. Thats the reason its throwing an error.

I dont have any official link